# Where does SharePoint store attachments?

Tags: attachments

I want to remove attachments from closed requests in order to optimize disk usage. However, when I tried to do so using RemoveAttachments API, nothing seems to change in terms of disk utilization, but attachments no longer exist in corresponding list items. 
Does SharePoint have something like vault for deleted files or so?

Comment: Do you mean like the Recycle bins? (At site and Site collection levels?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Items which is deleted from SharePoint list,libraries are not deleted permanently. It will goes to recycle bin. deleted items/Attachments will goes to "Recycle Bin" of site collection. You can view,restore,delete items from recycle bin.By default, items in the Recycle Bin are deleted automatically after 30 days.

Site Settings--> Site Collection Administration--> Recycle bin.

So for permanently remove attachments you have to delete it from Recycle bin.

In Office 365 there is option "Empty recycle bin". But in SharePoint on premises you have to perform following steps,**(USE IE Browser)**

1. Navigate to the recycle bin page (e.g., http://localhost/_layouts/recyclebin.aspx)
2. In the address bar, type “javascript:emptyItems()” (minus the quotes)
3. Press Enter. You will be asked if you really want to empty the recycle bin.
4. Click OK to empty it; click Cancel to leave it alone.

[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/330688/Completely-Empty-the-SharePoint-Recycle-Bin)

Comment: BTW, how do I remove everything  from recycle bin?  it shows  only 200 items per page, and I need to purge everything and there is no 'delete everything permanently' or so

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: “javascript:emptyItems()” did not work even in IE. it indeed asks  if i'm sure to delete all items but takes no effect

Comment: try using powershell. [Look this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/clear-sharepoint-sites-recycle-bin-using-powershell-script1)

Comment: you can use PowerShell script to remove the items from recycle bin.its uper fast and easily managable! :-). just you need to feed the site collec url into the script!

Answer (score -1):

Let the Recycle Bin "Naturally" purge itself out, even the Secondary Recycle Bin.
There are two Recycle Bins.  The Secondary Recycle bin by default holds item for an additional 50% longer.  This setting is only available to Site Collection Admins.